# "mysqld" vs "server" in my.cnf

Tags: mysql

I used to see server-related configuration in `my.cnf` located under `[mysqld]`.

However, I now come across configurations that use `[server]` instead.

It looks like both of them are synonyms, at least on MySQL 8.0, I can see that options under both groups apply to the MySQL server.

Is this a new feature of MySQL 8.0? Is one of them preferred over the other? Is one of them deprecated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the MySQL [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-options.html):

> mysqld reads options from the `[mysqld]` and `[server]` groups.

I could trace this back to MySQL 5.0, so this has been there for quite some time.